# sqoop to import data to hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, sqoop2, sql-manager

i am trying to import data to hive table using sqoop2. I am using `--hive-import` but it is not working

**Code:**

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.x.xxx:11xx --username user --password user --table xxxx.NOTIFICATION --hive-import
```

**Error:**

> ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'XXXX.NOTIFICATION'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi after doing a bit research and discussing on the question with @dev i found the solution.

I am using sqoop2 so i changed my command and used below one and it worked for me.

```
$ sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.x.xxx:11xx;database=SSSS;username=user;password=user" --query "SELECT * FROM xxxx.NOTIFICATION where \$CONDITIONS" --split-by xxxx.NOTIFICATION.ID --hive-import --hive-table NOTIFICATION  --target-dir NOTIFICATION
```

before executing this command we should create table in hive using `create` command. Here i have created hive table named `NOTIFICATION`.

Answer (score 1):

### Below observations are based on Sqoop 1.4.6

you are using **.** (dot) in your table name.

Internally, Sqoop will fire command

```
SELECT t.* FROM xxxx.NOTIFICATION AS t WHERE 1=0
```

to fetch metadata of your SQL Server table.

This command is interpreted as

- xxxx - schame name
- NOTIFICATION - Table name

To avoid this you can use escape character ( ***[ ]** in case of SQL Server*):

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.x.xxx:11xx --username user --password user --table [xxxx.NOTIFICATION] --hive-import`

This will generate

```
SELECT t.* FROM [xxxx.NOTIFICATION] AS t WHERE 1=0
```

Now `xxxx.NOTIFICATION` will be treated as table name.

Comment: xxxx.NOTIFICATION is my table name i tried using `--query` in my command and then it was working. I don't know what is the issue here

Comment: `$ sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.x.xxx:11xx;database=SSSS;username=user ;password=user " --query "SELECT * FROM XXXX.NOTIFICATION where \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir /user/cloudera/xxxxx -m 1`

Comment: i tried this and i am getting `ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '[XXXX.NOTIFICATION] AS t WHERE 1=0'.
`

Comment: @animal try my query put `--verbose` in the end of the command. share complete error logs

Comment: ok i'll share, but in my `--query` i am using databasename but in yours i am not seeing it

Comment: @animal I guess your issue will be resolved if you add databaseName is your connect parameter. e.g. `--connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:1433;databaseName=BCHN'`

Comment: i added it still the same issue is there

Comment: @animal is `xxxx` your database name ? or `xxxx.NOTIFICATION` is your  table name only?

Comment: `xxxx.NOTIFICATION` is my table name. My database name is `SSSS`

Comment: @animal  am just interested to see : `Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM [[XXXX.NOTIFICATION]] AS t WHERE 1=0 ` you can revert back your question as it has become lengthy. In your case it's already wrapped in   [] . just tell me the query I mentioned after removing [ ] in table name

Comment: `sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.x.xxx:11xx;databaseName=SSSS' --username user --password user --table xxxx.NOTIFICATION --hive-import --verbose`

Comment: @animal no I am asking for `Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM [[XXXX.NOTIFICATION]] AS t WHERE 1=0` in case of above query

Comment: I just want you to run- `sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.x.xxx:11xx;databaseName=SS‌​SS' --username user --password user --table xxxx.NOTIFICATION --hive-import --verbose` and look into the logs shown on shell and find  similar line `Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM [[XXXX.NOTIFICATION]] AS t WHERE 1=0`

Comment: sorry for late reply ! i executed and i am getting `Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM [XXXX.NOTIFICATION] AS t WHERE 1=0
`

Comment: @animal then it should work. query seems good. `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'XXXX.NOTIFICATION'.` this error is coming. right?

Comment: i have resolved this issue and posted my answer. Thanks for your help. I upvoted for your immense help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the table name is NOTIFICATION and you are trying to mention database name xxxx when you write --table xxxx.NOTIFICATION

If this is the case, can you please try the below mentioned syntax instead?

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.x.xxx:11xx;databaseName=xxxx --username user --password user --table NOTIFICATION --hive-import
```

Comment: No table name is `xxxx.NOTIFICATION` not `NOTIFICATION`

Comment: @animal did you get to try this? 

      sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.x.xxx:11xx;databaseName=SS‌​SS' --username user --password user --table xxxx\.NOTIFICATION --hive-import

Comment: yes i used it and i am getting `ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'xxxx.NOTIFICATION'.
`