# Import table from Windows SQL Server 2012 to hadoop using sqoop

Tags: sql-server, hadoop

I was trying to import a table from RDBMS (Windows - SQL Server 2012) to HDFS using the code below. But I'm getting an error. I could successfully connect it.

```
sqoop import   
--connect      
"jdbc:sqlserver://192.1x8.xx.1:14xx;database=AdventureWorks2012;
 username=hadox;password=hadxx" 
 --table Production.Product
     --hive-import
```

I understood the error was caused by the dot (.) in the tables name.

I got that information from the link [sqoop to import data to hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142141/sqoop-to-import-data-to-hive). I didn't understand any details in that link.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance.

Error:

> ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'Production.Product'.
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'Production.Product'.

Comment: Did you try `AdventureWorks2012.Production.Product` ?

Comment: sorry philanrovert, I am really new to the applications. where would I be writing this?

Comment: with `--table` or maybe try a query with `--query "SELECT * from AdventureWorks2012.Production.Product WHERE \$CONDITIONS"

Comment: Thanks philantrovert. I used query sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://

Comment: Thanks philantrovert. I used query sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.xx.1:14xx;username=xx;password=xx" --query "SELECT* FROM AdventureWorks2012.Production.Product WHERE \$CONDITIONS" --SPLIT-BY ProductID --hive-import --hive-table --target-dir /user/local/hive/Adventure2012. I was not getting any error, but saying "missing arguiment for option: hive-table. nd also giving a list of sqoop import [GENERIC-ARGS] [TOOL-ARGS]

Comment: IDON'T UNDERSTAND WHAT DOES THAT MEAN

Comment: If you want to directly import it to Hive Table you have to provide a table name after --hive-table. Like `--hive-table table_in_hive`.

Comment: I am getting the following error as follows: 17/09/19 09:41:00 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:10002. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
17/09/19 09:41:00 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hadoop1 cause:java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:10002 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: 17/09/19 09:41:00 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:10002 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1136)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1112)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)

Comment: Is your cluster Kerberos enable? I think you should raise a separate question for this. Make sure to highlight whatever you have done till now.

Comment: The command used: sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.xx.x:1xxx;username=xxx;passwo‌​rd=xxx" --query "SELECT* FROM AdventureWorks2012.Production.Product WHERE \$CONDITIONS" --split-by ProductID --hive-table ProductionProduct --target-dir /usr/local/hive/AdventureWorks2012.Thanks for your advice and being patient. Sorry for being a pain again!!

Comment: I don't know about Kerberos ! i will google it and make sure. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Please ask a new Stackoverflow question. You are unlikely to get any help here.

Comment: When I check whether SQL server was connnected with the code "sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.xx.1:14xx --username xxx --password xxx " I got the list below. Isn't the sign that Kerberos is enabled? 
Warning: /usr/local/hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /usr/lib/hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Comment: 17/09/19 10:13:42 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/09/19 10:13:42 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
master
tempdb
model
msdb
ReportServer$SQLSERVERBI
ReportServer$SQLSERVERBITempDB
AdventureWorks2012

Comment: As you said I may raise a separate question.

Comment: Hi philantrovert, can I ask if kerberos is a default server in ubuntu/hadoop?

Comment: No, forget about Kerberos thing. You just need to mention the query that you are running, what you are trying to achieve , and the error that you have been getting

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally sqoop will consider Production as schemaname (database name) Product as the table name.
if you want to use import the table into production database, product table in hive. I would suggest  you to use --query in sqoop command using that you are specifying the sqoop to look for specific table.

Comment: Thanks for this information Ankush. sorry, can you say it with an example, please? An example will be helpful to understand bit easily as I am a kindergarten child to any applications:-)